# ้Highlight expired next 6 month

Tags: excel, vba

Confirm the completeness of the cord in searching for products that will expire in the next 6 months by highlighting only days 1-30 (in the next 6 months) only, otherwise nothing else.

I have an example. But couldn't highlight until the 30th of that month.

```vb
Sub test()
 Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim todayDate As Date
    Dim sixMonthsLater As Date
    Dim expiryColumn As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    
    ' Set the worksheet object to the desired worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") ' Replace "Sheet1" with your sheet name
    
    ' Get the last row in the worksheet
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "N").End(xlUp).Row
    
    ' Set the expiry column range
    Set expiryColumn = ws.Range("N2:N" & lastRow)
    
    ' Get the current date
    todayDate = Date
    
    ' Calculate the date six months later
    sixMonthsLater = DateAdd("m", 6, todayDate)
    
    ' Loop through the cells in the expiry column
    For Each cell In expiryColumn
        ' Check if the expiry date is within the next 6 months and the month is the 6th month
        If cell.Value > todayDate And cell.Value <= sixMonthsLater And Month(cell.Value) = Month(sixMonthsLater) Then
            ' Apply formatting to the cell
            cell.EntireRow.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 127, 80) ' Orange color
        End If
    Next cell
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

- Get the first day and the last day of the target month (6 mths later)
- Look for a cell value is within the target month

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub test()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim sixMonthsLater As Date
    Dim expiryColumn As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    ' Set the worksheet object to the desired worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") ' Replace "Sheet1" with your sheet name
    ' Get the last row in the worksheet
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "N").End(xlUp).Row
    ' Set the expiry column range
    Set expiryColumn = ws.Range("N2:N" & lastRow)
    Dim Yr As Long, Mth As Long
    Dim StartDay As Date, EndDay As Date
    ' Calculate the date six months later
    sixMonthsLater = DateAdd("m", 6, Date)
    Yr = Year(sixMonthsLater)
    Mth = Month(sixMonthsLater)
    StartDay = DateSerial(Yr, Mth, 1)
    EndDay = DateSerial(Yr, Mth + 1, 0)
    Debug.Print StartDay, EndDay ' for testing
    ' Loop through the cells in the expiry column
    expiryColumn.EntireRow.Interior.Pattern = xlNone
    For Each cell In expiryColumn
        ' Check if the expiry date is within the next 6 months and the month is the 6th month
        If cell.Value >= StartDay And cell.Value <= EndDay Then
            ' Apply formatting to the cell
            cell.EntireRow.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 127, 80) ' Orange color
        End If
    Next cell
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your good wishes.

But it also highlight 1-5 month (I only want another 6 months to expire from 1-30

Comment: `highlighting only days 1-30` are you intend to exclude 31? My code will highlight any cells between 2024/5/1  ~  2024/5/31.

Comment: I'm worried about months 30,31, I just hope 30 days covers it all. If you can distinguish the months 28,30,31, it will be even better.

Comment: You don't need to worry about it. My code can handle it.  I have tested code w/o issues on M365. Please add `Debug.Print StartDay, EndDay` before for loop to check the date range.

Comment: Thank you very much for this help. I just hope my cord can ignore months 1-5 and highlight only month 6 from 1-31.

Comment: I knew what was happen on your pc. The highlight on months 1~5 are from your original code. Please check the updated code. Add `expiryColumn.EntireRow.Interior.Pattern = xlNone` before for loop to remove the color formatting.